# 'Cannot connect to server' error appears randomly after API request from UI does not reach to java backend servlet

Tags: java, angular, servlets, servlet-filters, servlet-listeners

Response headers are coming as empty for the API request. We do not observe this error every time we send the request from UI, this behavior is random. As the request is not reaching backend servlet, no logs are available in the backend.
Mainly observed this issue while downloading offline Excel report from the server.
VM used is CentOS